# Is there a way to return a value from a stored procedure inside a case?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to return a value from a stored procedure and then call this stored procedure inside another procedure that will be evaluated in a `CASE WHEN` statement. With the code below it will be more clear I hope.

First stored procedure that will insert a row

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBook]
    @bookName VARCHAR(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Book] (bookName)
    VALUES (@bookName)
```

Second stored procedure that will return a value based on a if/else condition

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[verifyBook]
    @bookName VARCHAR(50)
    IF (@bookName = 'A')
    BEGIN 
        EXEC [dbo].[InsertBook] @bookName = 'A'
        SELECT 1
    END
    ELSE IF (@bookName = 'B')
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 0
    END
```

Third stored procedure that will verify the value returned by the second stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectBook]
    @bookName VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT
        id, name, 
        CASE 
           WHEN [dbo].[verifyBook] @bookName =  1 
              THEN TRUE 
              ELSE FALSE 
        END AS Status
       FROM Books
```

But i have an error in my third stored procedure :

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected
```

With a function I don't have the problem but I will need a stored procedure to insert data.

How to verify the value returned by a stored procedure in a `CASE WHEN`?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you have omit paremeter on second and third procedure and other the As after procedure name ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? This logic is backwards. The second proc actually calls the first and inserts a bookName of A 100% of the time, since `verifyBook` doesn't have any parameters. The `ELSE IF` will never be evaluated, and it isn't a correct `ELSE IF` statement since it doesn't catch all other cases. You have an XY Problem... meaning you are asking how to do X to solve Y but in reality the issue is with Y. Tell us what the ultimate goal or problem you are trying to solve is. What you have shown is, arguably, the wrong way to do anything, no matter what it is.

Comment: The purpose of this is to display a status of the book based of the result of a storeproc. I just omitted to put a parameter in the second proc. But the problem is not there

Comment: Just query the table... no need to execute another proc... just query the table to see if it is there. Why complicate it? Point is, you can't use a stored proc like that and shouldn't...

Comment: Here i just put a small example. But my stored procedure is more complex with a lot of codes hence i dont want to put everything in one stored procedure. And what you mean about just Query the table ? Please read my post again to understand my problem and my need

Comment: I did, multiple times. `verifyBook` calls  proc `InsertBook` that inserts a book name. You want to check if that book name was inserted... or a specific bookname was inserted it seems. This is what is unclear. Regardless, we can't help you without you clarifying and over simplifying your code only to say *its complex*

Comment: I don't want to check if my bookname was inserted. I want to return a value 0 or 1 based on the value of the BookName. The value 0 or 1 will be returned to  my third stored procedure that fetch all the booKname in my books table and for each bookname it will execute the [dbo].[verifyBook]

Comment: The problem is here : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected. And this is what i should fix. With a function i have no problem, but with a function i cannot insert a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SELECT` inside a stored procedure outputs a Resultset, not a return value or an output parameter.  You can INSERT … EXEC to load the results into a table variable or temp table.

EG

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selectBook
    @bookName VARCHAR(50)
as 
begin
  declare @v table(status bit);
  insert into @v exec dbo.verifyBook @bookName;
  select status from @v; 
end
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That's what i needed. I dont know why some  other people are just rude and belittle others by thinking themselves smarter than others without giving a solution